# How can i access an activity from another feature module

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I am creating an instant app, which include application module, base feature module, instant app module and an another feature module. Problem is i am not able to access the activities of application module from base-feature and feature module and same between base-feature module and feature module but i am able to access activity of base-feature module from application module.

Right now i am accessing the activities using :

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,
                    Class.forName("com.demo.test.appmodule.TextActivity"));
```

by this method studio don't show me any errors at compile time.

1. Is there any other way for communication between two different feature modules?
2. Why i am able to access base-feature module activity from application module but not vice versa?
3. can we access activities of application module from base or any other feature module?

[image: project structure]

[image]

Can i have a link which define the project structure for an instant app

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

The reason why you can't communicate directly between features is because they're independent from one another.

The correct way to handle this is calling it with its URL, example: [android-instant-apps/hello-feature-module/HelloActivity.java](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-instant-apps/blob/master/hello-feature-module/features/hello/src/main/java/com/instantappsamples/feature/hello/HelloActivity.java)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
Uri.parse("https://hello-feature.instantappsample.com/goodbye"));
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
startActivity(intent);
```

In an instant-app structure, the *base acts as a library* for the feature modules, and the features are built into *APKs*. In an installed-app structure, *both the base and features act as libraries* for the application module. Some explanation can be found here:

- [Why use the new Android feature plugin over the library plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44361335/why-use-the-new-android-feature-plugin-over-the-library-plugin/44361564#44361564)
- [Android: Can you add activities to the Instant App module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47425735/android-can-you-add-activities-to-the-instant-app-module/47430978#47430978)

There used to be a page @ https://g.co/instantapps that explained the structure of instant apps, but looks like it's missing. However, you can take a look at:

- https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/08/android-instant-apps-best-practices-for.html
- bottom of page @ [codelabs/android-multi-feature-instant-app/#3](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-multi-feature-instant-app/#3)

And no, you won't be able to directly access activities of the application from a feature. As an installed-app, **`com.android.feature`** modules are compiled/behave as **`com.android.library`** modules, so apply the same rules here: the application depends on the library, not the other way around. To traverse that direction, you will need to use the same kind of Intent as shown above.

Anything in **`com.android.application`** will be isolated from the feature modules of the instant-app, and will only appear in the installed-app.