# Android instant feature: Is it something fundamentally flawed with this approach?

Tags: java, android, firebase, gradle, android-instant-apps

I'm trying to make my app to build again after updating from google gradle plugin 3.1.4 to the now latest 3.2.1 and I think there maybe something wrong with the approach I took to make my instantapp work in first place, so I post this question to discard or confirm that, and in such case to ask for a different approach.

Briefly, my app is a game with many graphics in the assets folder. To make the instantapp fit into the 10 megabyte limit imposed by Google Play, I had to remove some of these assets that I won't need in the instant version and also those with higher resolution, while keeping the rest. Also the instantapp has slightly different code than the installed one, so I override some methods and classes there.

The minimal com.android.instantapp module cannot contain assets and code, it seemed, so I created an intermediary feature module which hold these instead.

So, after a lot of struggle (mainly with firebase and the com.google.gms.google-services plugins) I came up with this approach that eventually worked with the version 3.1.4 of the gradle plugin (com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4)

[image: my current approach]

The only weird thing there, is that I had to set the flag "baseFeature" to both, the android_instant_feature and the android_common feature modules. But it worked and I could finally publish an instant version of my game, while the installed version continued building just fine too.

Now, as soon as I update to version 3.2.1 of the google gradle plugin, the problems begins even if I do not change anything else. I got a lot of errors of this sort when trying to build the project:

```
Unable to find a matching variant of project :android_common:
  - Variant 'debugApiElements':
      - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
      - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
      - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Metadata' and found incompatible value 'Aar'.
      - Found org.gradle.usage 'java-api' but wasn't required.
  - Variant 'debugFeatureApiElements':
      - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
      - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debugFeature' but wasn't required.
      - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Metadata' and found incompatible value 'Feature'.
      - Found org.gradle.usage 'java-api' but wasn't required.
  - Variant 'debugFeatureRuntimeElements':
      - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
      - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debugFeature' but wasn't required.
      - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Metadata' and found incompatible value 'Feature'.
      - Found org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' but wasn't required.
  - Variant 'debugRuntimeElements':
      - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
      - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
      - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Metadata' and found incompatible value 'Aar'.
      - Found org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' but wasn't required.
  - Variant 'releaseApiElements':
      - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found incompatible value 'release'.
      - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
      - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Metadata' and found incompatible value 'Aar'.
      - Found org.gradle.usage 'java-api' but wasn't required.
  - Variant 'releaseFeatureApiElements':
      - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found incompatible value 'release'.
      - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'releaseFeature' but wasn't required.
      - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Metadata' and found incompatible value 'Feature'.
      - Found org.gradle.usage 'java-api' but wasn't required.
  - Variant 'releaseFeatureRuntimeElements':
      - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found incompatible value 'release'.
      - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'releaseFeature' but wasn't required.
      - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Metadata' and found incompatible value 'Feature'.
      - Found org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' but wasn't required.
  - Variant 'releaseRuntimeElements':
      - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found incompatible value 'release'.
      - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
      - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Metadata' and found incompatible value 'Aar'.
      - Found org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' but wasn't required.
```

After some tweaking with the gradle scripts, including removing the baseFeature true flag from the android_instant_feature module, I got a briefer error, but I cannot really say whether I'm better off than before. The error is this:

> Expected configuration
>   ':android_instant_feature:debugFeatureCompileClasspath' to contain
>   exactly one file, however, it contains no files.

And now I'm just blocked here without knowing what to do or where to look next, so I wonder if there's something fundamentally flawed with my approach in first place, since I came up with it after some trial and error and I'm not sure it's fine, and in such case which other approach I could use that fulfills my requirements and those from Google, whichever they are.

These are my Gradle Files for these modules, as per request of @TWL. I have replaced the real app id with com.myapp.id, the rest is exactly what I have, including a lot of stuff for libGDX that I think is irrelevant for the matter, though I prefer to leave it there in the name of accuracy:

**android_common**:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.feature"

configurations { natives }

android {
    baseFeature true
    compileSdkVersion 28
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }

        androidTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        sourceSets {
            all {
                manifest.srcFile "AndroidManifest.xml"
            }
        }
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            setMinifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
    }
}

dependencies {
    application project(':android')
    implementation project(':core')
    api 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
    implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
    implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing:$playBillingLibVersion"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1"

    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:24.0-android'
}

task copyAndroidNatives() {
    file("libs/armeabi/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/armeabi-v7a/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/arm64-v8a/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/x86_64/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/x86/").mkdirs();

    configurations.natives.files.each { jar ->
        def outputDir = null
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-arm64-v8a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/arm64-v8a")
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi-v7a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi-v7a")
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi")
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86_64.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86_64")
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86")
        if (outputDir != null) {
            copy {
                from zipTree(jar)
                into outputDir
                include "*.so"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**android_instant_feature**:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.feature"

android {
//    baseFeature true
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.2"
    compileSdkVersion 28
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ["${project(':android_common').projectDir}/res"]
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }
    defaultConfig {
        versionCode 4031
        versionName "4.1.2.1i"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
    }

    // Proguard configuration
    buildTypes {
        release {
            //minifyEnabled true will turn proguard ON
//            minifyEnabled true
            //proguardFiles let you add your own proguard rules ('proguard-project.txt') in this case, as its already created by gdx-setup
//            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
        debug {}
    }


    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

task run(type: Exec) {
    def path
    def localProperties = project.file("../local.properties")
    if (localProperties.exists()) {
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        localProperties.withInputStream { instr ->
            properties.load(instr)
        }
        def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
        if (sdkDir) {
            path = sdkDir
        } else {
            path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
        }
    } else {
        path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
    }

    def adb = path + "/platform-tools/adb"
    commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'com.marzoa.ruletafree/com.marzoa.ruletafree.AndroidLauncher'
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(":core")
    feature project(":android_common")
    api 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
    implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-instantapps:16.0.0'

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**android_instant**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.instantapp'

android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.id"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(":android_common")
    implementation project(":android_instant_feature")
}
```

**android**:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: 'io.fabric' // Needed by crashlytics. DO NOT REMOVE.

android {
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.2"
    compileSdkVersion 28
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ["${project(':android_common').projectDir}/res"]
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }

        androidTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.id"
        versionCode 4032
        versionName "4.1.2.1"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
    }
    // Proguard configuration
    buildTypes {
        release {
            //minifyEnabled true will turn proguard ON
            minifyEnabled true
            //proguardFiles let you add your own proguard rules ('proguard-project.txt') in this case, as its already created by gdx-setup
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

task importPuzzles(type: Exec) {
    // TODO
}

task run(type: Exec) {
    def path
    def localProperties = project.file("../local.properties")
    if (localProperties.exists()) {
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        localProperties.withInputStream { instr ->
            properties.load(instr)
        }
        def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
        if (sdkDir) {
            path = sdkDir
        } else {
            path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
        }
    } else {
        path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
    }

    def adb = path + "/platform-tools/adb"
    commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'com.marzoa.ruletafree/com.myapp.id.AndroidLauncher'
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(":core")
    implementation project(":android_common")
    api 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
    implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
    implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing:$playBillingLibVersion"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1"
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5'

    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: This is curious, I was only able to reproduce your "new error" if I left the com.android.instantapp module empty of dependencies..., but of course, there should only be one `baseFeature`, but the issue is probably with how you configured your gradle files to tie together the structure/dependencies of your instant/app, can you show them?

Comment: Also reproducible if the instantapp module did not include the `base`

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering, @TWL. The dependencies of my android_instant instantapp module aren't blank, though it has just two of them: the android_common module and the android_instant_feature one. The rest of the needed stuff is already in android_common or android_instant_feature. It's late at night here, but I promise you I'll upload the skimmed gradle files tomorrow.

Comment: @TWL I have updated my question adding the Gradle files. Please note that I have replaced the real app id with com.myapp.id instead. Bests!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for providing the gradle files and looks like your gradle dependencies were mixed up.

The `com.android.feature` module that holds the `baseFeature true` should be the one whose dependencies also hold both the `application project()` and `feature project()`. That’s the main cause of your error:

> Expected configuration ':___:debugFeatureCompileClasspath' to contain
>   exactly one file, however, it contains no files.

So from what you provided, it looks like your `application project()` and `feature project()` are separated.

To fix this, your “*base*” `android_common` should be:

```
application project(':android')
feature project(":android_instant_feature")
```

And your “*non-base feature*” `android_instant_feature` should be:

```
implementation project(':android_common)
```

This won’t change the overall structure of your project.

- Your `com.android.application` will be compiled with the libraries: `core` and `android_common`.
- Your `com.android.instantapp` will be compiled with the instant app apks: `android_common.apk` and `android_instant_feature.apk`.

Now, why did it work with 2x `baseFeature` before ? I don’t know, it shouldn’t have...

There used to be a page @ https://g.co/instantapps that explained the structure of instant apps, but you can refer to one of my previous posts that touches on it for an overview and reference links: [How can i access an activity from another feature module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51035892/how-can-i-access-an-activity-from-another-feature-module/51049978#51049978)

*Side note*: I noticed that you have a `implementation project(":core")` common throughout your modules (minus the instantapp). If that is purely a library like `com.android.library`, then you shouldn’t have to set it up like that. You can actually just place it in your *base* as: `api project(":core")` and removing all other references elsewhere. Declaring it as `api` means that any module that also implements the base will also be exposed to this dependency. (*Try it, there are some rare cases where this is bugged depending on what other libs your `core` has, but try and see*).

Comment: Thanks a million! This is working. :) To add to your answer, I had to change minSDKVersion too, because I have some places with 15 and others with 16, which is obviously a mistake and unrelated to my previous problems. Again, many thanks.